# How to downgrade Cython in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, installation, pip, virtualenv, cython

How do I downgrade Cython in a virtualenv?

I created it like this:

```
virtualenv -p python3.4 .
pip install cython
```

then it installed version `Cython-0.22.1.tar.gz`.
However, I am trying to install `Kivy` in a virtualenv and apparently Cython has a bug that doesn't allow `pip install kivy` to complete successfully, when that version of Cython is installed. Some people mentioned that you have to downgrade Cython, in order to get Kivy to compile.

So I tried:

```
pip uninstall cython
pip install cython 0.20
```

which gives me:

```
Using cached Cython-0.22.1.tar.gz
Collecting 0.21.2
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 0.21.2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for 0.21.2
```

So it seems the older version of Cython is somehow not available?

How do I downgrade then?

**EDIT#1**:
Output of `pip --version`:
    pip 7.1.0

Comment: I guess you are looking for  `pip install cython==0.20`

Comment: Let me guess what this is for, Kivy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `cel` mentioned in this comment the correct command for this purpose is not `pip install cython 0.20` but `pip install cython==0.20`. This solved my problem and the following Kivy installation (`pip install kivy`) ran through without errors.

Maybe this will be useful to someone stumbling over this answer:

Complete procedure to setup a virtualenv for developing with Kivy:

1. Dependencies which need to be installed:

   1. `sudo apt-get install mercurial`
   2. `sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-numpy libsdl-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsmpeg-dev libportmidi-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev`
   3. `sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame`
2. Create the virtualenv

   1. `virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute -p python3.4`
3. setup the virtualenv

   1. `pip install --upgrade pip`
   2. `pip install cython==0.20`
   3. `pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`
   4. `pip install kivy`

Answer (score 2):

Which version of pip are you using?

- pip < 6.0 then run the install with the `--ignore-installed` option
- pip >= 6.0 then use the `--no-cache-dir` option

Comment: Added information about used pip version in my post.